# Update html table cell data after table sort

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have html table that get data from mysql.
Every 5 seconds I check if there is any changes in mysql table using ajax and update specific html table cells.

Now I want to use this nice jquery plugin:
http://mitya.co.uk/scripts/Table-sort---now-REGEXP-friendly-111

So there is a plan:
1. Load table
2. Every 5 sec check if any cells are need to be updated
3. Run jquery table sort plugin.

The question is how to find html cell which I want to update? After sorting all data is moving in table.

I tried to load table from my sql by:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<tr id='{$row[id]}'>
```

But sorting plugin moving only data. Not entire html rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use jquery's empty() function to empty out the table and then redraw all the rows?

Alternatively, you could use the id attribute to reference a specific row using the table's unique index.
ex: `<tr id="row<?=$row->id?>"><td id="name<?=$row->id?>"><?=$row->name?></td><td id="count<?=$row->id?>" ><?=$row->count?></td></tr>`

and then use jquery to update each rows content accordingly